# how to show json data in the data table using ajax call in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to show JSON data in the datatable. getting JSON from API but unable to show in the table. I have 4 columns in the table but I want to show only 3 cols in the table.data table working with my this c# code

```
return Json(new { data=data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but not working with this code

```
return Json(data.Select(d => new { sms=d.sms,id= d.id,updtd_date = d.updtd_date.ToString()}).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

error

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
```

JSON sample data.

```
[{"sms":"Alert: Tank is Full","id":1027,"updtd_date":"7/6/2017 6:39:45 AM"},...]
```

AJAX call

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/WaterLevel/getSMS",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns" : [
                    { "data": "updtd_date", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "sms", "autoWidth": true }
                    ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please add to your question that you add use this: https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

Updated the Ajax call.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    "ajax": {
               "dataType": 'json',
               "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               "type": "GET",
               "url":"/WaterLevel/getSMS",
               "dataSrc": function (json) {
                return $.parseJSON(json);
                                 }

                    },
                    "columns" : [
                        { "data": "updtd_date", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "sms", "autoWidth": true }
                        ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: actually i dont want to hide the col. i just wanted to show the cols which are in my json data. while im showing its showing no records, may be some error in my cols in the ajax call.

Comment: 1.Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
2.XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: http://localhost:50389/49715571c0924dcda79bd63b6ebe036a/browserLinkSignalR/abort?transport=webSockets&....

Comment: Those errors are not related to the current code which you have posted. Need more info on your code.

Comment: XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: localhost:this is the error.if i use this code "  return Json(new { data=data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);", its working, but when i change to "return Json(data.Select(d => new { sms=d.sms,id= d.id,updtd_date = d.updtd_date.ToString()}).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);"its giving error

Comment: Can you update ajax call and include  `contentType: "application/json",` and try it.

Comment: not working , error- TypeError: f is undefined. there is error in columns of ajax call.

Comment: error-""SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data".//return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );

Comment: Can you debug ajax call and update your question with that json response.

Comment: "ReferenceError: data is not defined".ReferenceError: dataSrc is not defined // { "data": ...}